# Is there a simple way to load/read CSV/JSON image dataset labeled using Labelbox

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I have labeled my image dataset using Labelbox. The output format is CSV. Which contain links to images and its labels. how can I read this dataset, I am using google collab with TensorFlow 2.0.
This is how the CSV look like when opened in excel
[image: this is how the CSV look like when opened in excel]

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to know more about the specific intake format you're using for the model architecture.

Labelbox CSV Exports are set up with various identifying information about the label in each row, including a link to the image, however, the actual label itself is a JSON object within the "Label" column. (info here: https://labelbox.com/docs/exporting-data/export-format-detail)

The format of the JSON depends on the format of your data ontology, but generally speaking will be:

{"Class/Object Name": [ {instance1}, {instance2}, ... ], ...}

where for bounding boxes/polygons each instance has a key "geometry" that leads to an x, y point list.

if you can clarify what expected format you're looking for, and what format your objects are in, I can help more with conversion